# active_file memory is not considered as available memory

Tags: linux, kubernetes, memory

I would like to ask your opinion about what is said in [the official kubernetes documentation here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#active-file-memory-is-not-considered-as-available-memory).

The doc states "The kubelet treats active_file memory areas as not reclaimable" but by conducting some experiments I was able to see how that memory is actually recovered, I also find confirmation in other articles like [this](https://itnext.io/from-rss-to-wss-navigating-the-depths-of-kubernetes-memory-metrics-4d7d77d8fdcb) which I found very interesting

I'm a little confused on this issue but it is of fundamental importance to understand how to appropriately set the memory limits in those pods that make extensive use of I/O

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as it means that active_file is not considered as available memory when scheduling pods by the kubelet even though it is technically reclaimable by the kernel. One good reason as it may seem is that the kubelet does not have access to the same information as the kernel about which memory pages are active. And also because the kubelet can't accurately predict which memory pages will be available in the future, avoiding the risk of evicting a pod using an active memory.

Comment: Ok I understand that it's not considered when scheduling, but what I need to know is if once pod approacches its memory limit, its active file memory is reclaimed or not, for what I saw the answer is yes, what do you think?